# onBindViewHolder method accept first first parameter only

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make recycler view in kotlin my CustomAdapter class of onBindViewHolder method only accept first dataholder of **model class**. 
onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) this method only accept fname

```
class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<Person>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val myView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(myView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return userList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

       holder?.firstName?.text = userList[position].fname

       holder.address?.text = userList[position].address //this method give me error
       holder.myage.text = userList[position].age      //this method give me error
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val firstName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtname)
        val address = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtaddress)
        val myage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtage)
    }

}
```

**this is a model class**

```
class Person(val fname: String, address: String, age :Int){


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `val` in front of each variable that you want to retrieve

```
class Person(val fname: String, val address: String, val age :Int){}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use data class

```
data class Person(val fname: String, val address: String, val age: Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access only the values or the variables which is defined in the "model" class only. Here I can see you're defining only **fname** as a value in your data class constuctor and that's why It fails to access the other prams in the constructors. try this -

`data class Person(val fname: String, val address: String, val age :Int){}`